# Mockito How to mock only the call of a method of the superclass

Tags: java, mockito

I'm using Mockito in some tests.

I have the following classes:

```
class BaseService {  
    public void save() {...}  
}

public Childservice extends BaseService {  
    public void save(){  
        //some code  
        super.save();
    }  
}
```

I want to mock only the second call (`super.save`) of `ChildService`. The first call must call the real method. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can this be solved with PowerMockito?

Comment: @javaPlease42: Yes you can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23884011/2049986.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

No, Mockito does not support this.

This might not be the answer you're looking for, but what you're seeing is a symptom of not applying the design principle:

> [Favor composition over inheritance](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/11/favor-composition-over-inheritance-and-other-pithy-catch-phrases.aspx)

If you extract a strategy instead of extending a super class the problem is gone.

If however you are not allowed to change the code, but you must test it anyway, and in this awkward way, there is still hope. With some AOP tools (for example AspectJ) you can weave code into the super class method and avoid its execution entirely (yuck). This doesn't work if you're using proxies, you have to use bytecode modification (either load time weaving or compile time weaving). There are be mocking frameworks that support this type of trick as well, like PowerMock and PowerMockito.

I suggest you go for the refactoring, but if that is not an option you're in for some serious hacking fun.

Comment: I'm not seeing the LSP violation. I have roughly the same setup as the OP: a base DAO class with a findAll() method, and a subclass DAO that overrides the base method by calling super.findAll() and then sorting the result. The subclass is substitutable into all contexts accepting the superclass. Am I misunderstanding your meaning?

Comment: I'll remove the LSP remark (it doesn't add value to the answer).

Comment: Yes inheritance sucks and the stupid framework I'm stuck with is designed with inheritance as the only option.

Comment: Assuming you can't redesign the superclass, you could extract the `//some codes` code into a method that could be tested separately.

Comment: Mockito does support this with spying and there are legit reasons to use this such as extending a class from a library. In Android for example, you have to extend Activity class and you want to mock getIntent() for example.

Comment: @GuillaumePerrot do you have working code showing that this works with Mockito? I think you are mistaken, because a class calling super is not the same as spying one of the object's methods for _external_ calls.

Comment: @iwein it's this answer which has more votes by the way ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/3838664/598520  And the proof it works in my scenario:  https://github.com/Microsoft/mobile-center-sdk-android/blob/distribution/sdk/mobile-center-updates/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/mobile/updates/DeepLinkActivityTest.java#L68  It's not thanks to powermock, I use it for a static call there which has nothing to do with spy.

Comment: @GuillaumePerrot that answer has "//save method of super will still be called" in it. I really think there is a misunderstanding here. Vanilla Mockito does not support intersecting the stack between a class and it's superclass.

Comment: Ok got it. It's a different problem than what I was trying to solve when I looked for this, but at least that misunderstanding solved my own issue to mock call from base class (that I don't override indeed).

Comment: "Favor composition over inheritance". AAAAAHHHHH!!!!!  is a has a is a has a is a has a is a has a ...

Comment: "Favour composition over inheritance WHERE IT MAKES SENSE to do so." If you only need to modify certain behaviour, it doesn't make sense to write a wrapper that invokes every method on the wrapped object, except those methods you want to have different behaviour. It'll blow up as soon as the interface is extended. Case in point: a `SimpleJpaRepository` where the `delete` method marks an entity as deleted, rather than deleting it altogether.

Comment: @SeverityOne in this particular case, that design principle makes a lot of sense, that's the reason I mentioned it all those years ago. That said, I'd much rather code in a language that doesn't have inheritance than a language that doesn't have composition. I've written maintainable code without inheritance many times. So I'd propose that favouring composition over inheritance always makes sense, even if you grudgingly use inheritance sometimes when your favour isn't strong enough.

Answer (score 105):

If you really don't have a choice for refactoring you can mock/stub everything in the super method call e.g.

```
    class BaseService {

        public void validate(){
            fail(" I must not be called");
        }

        public void save(){
            //Save method of super will still be called.
            validate();
        }
    }

    class ChildService extends BaseService{

        public void load(){}

        public void save(){
            super.save();
            load();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSave() {
        ChildService classToTest = Mockito.spy(new ChildService());

        // Prevent/stub logic in super.save()
        Mockito.doNothing().when((BaseService)classToTest).validate();

        // When
        classToTest.save();

        // Then
        verify(classToTest).load();
    }
```

Comment: this code wouldn't actually prevent the super.save() invocation right, so if you do a lot in the super.save() you'd have to prevent all those calls...

Comment: fantastic solution works wonders for me when I want to return a mocked value from a superclass method for use by the child, fantastic thank you.

Comment: this works nice unless the validate is hidden or the save method does the work directly instead of calling an other method. mockito does not:
Mockito.doNothing().when((BaseService)spy).save();
this will not 'doNothing on the base service save but on the childService save :(

Comment: I can't get this to work on mine - it stubs out the child method too. `BaseService` is abstract, though I don't see why that would be relevant.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat yea i'm seeing the same thing :( anyone know how to get it to only stub out the `super.validate()`?

Comment: @stantonk you'll need to use an additional framework (see also discussion below my answer). This answer is handy, but it doesn't answer the specifics of the question, as you've found out.

Comment: Just what I needed. Wrapped the super method code in another method and was good to go. Thanks!

Comment: @tibi just create a parameterized constructor with a boolean param, then save value to a class field, which will act as a switch to invoke or not superclass method call and during test use that constructor to disable that call in tested class. It's fine to use such behavior if testing of a superclass method call result is not relevant in your test.

Comment: great solution! I didn't know that I could use `@Spy` for that!

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to suppress the superclass method using PowerMockito. 3 simple steps need for this

1. Use **PowerMockito.suppress** method and **MemberMatcher.methodsDeclaredIn** method to supress parent class method
2. Second **add Parent class in @PrepareForTest**
3. Run your test class with PowerMock ie add **@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)** above your test class.

   ```
   @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
   @PrepareForTest({BaseService.class})
   public class TestChildService(){

       @Spy
       private ChildService testChildServiceObj = Mockito.spy(new ChildService());

       @Test
       public void testSave(){
           PowerMockito.suppress(MemberMatcher.methodsDeclaredIn(BaseService.class));

           //your further test code

           testChildServiceObj.save();
       }
   }
   ```

Note: This will work only when the superclass method does not return anything.

Answer (score 6):

Consider refactoring the code from ChildService.save() method to different method and test that new method instead of testing ChildService.save(), this way you will avoid unnecessary call to super method.

Example:

```
class BaseService {  
    public void save() {...}  
}

public Childservice extends BaseService {  
    public void save(){  
        newMethod();    
        super.save();
    }
    public void newMethod(){
       //some codes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the easiest option if inheritance makes sense is to create a new method (package private??) to call the super (lets call it superFindall), spy the real instance and then mock the superFindAll() method in the way you wanted to mock the parent class one. It's not the perfect solution in terms of coverage and visibility but it should do the job and it's easy to apply.

```
 public Childservice extends BaseService {
    public void save(){
        //some code
        superSave();
    }

    void superSave(){
        super.save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create a package protected (assumes test class in same package) method in the sub class that calls the super class method and then call that method in your overridden sub class method.  you can then set expectations on this method in your test through the use of the spy pattern.  not pretty but certainly better than having to deal with all the expectation setting for the super method in your test

Comment: can I also say that composition over inheritance is almost always better, but sometimes its simply just simpler to use inheritance.  until java incorporates a better compositional model, like scala or groovy, this will always be the case and this issue will continue to exist

Answer (score 1):

Even if i totally agree with iwein response (

> favor composition over inheritance

), i admit there are some times inheritance seems just natural, and i don't feel breaking or refactor it just for the sake of a unit test.

So, my suggestion :

```
/**
 * BaseService is now an asbtract class encapsulating 
 * some common logic callable by child implementations
 */
abstract class BaseService {  
    protected void commonSave() {
        // Put your common work here
    }

    abstract void save();
}

public ChildService extends BaseService {  
    public void save() {
        // Put your child specific work here
        // ...

        this.commonSave();
    }  
}
```

And then, in the unit test :

```
    ChildService childSrv = Mockito.mock(ChildService.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);

    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation)
                throws Throwable {
            // Put your mocked behavior of BaseService.commonSave() here
            return null;
        }
    }).when(childSrv).commonSave();

    childSrv.save();

    Mockito.verify(childSrv, Mockito.times(1)).commonSave();

    // Put any other assertions to check child specific work is done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with PowerMockito and replace behavior only of the parent class method with continuing testing the child's class method. Even when the method is returning some value, lets say a string, you can do something like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ BaseService.class })
public class TestChildService() {

    private BasicService basicServiceObj;
    private ChildService testee;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        testee = new ChildService();
        basicServiceObj = PowerMockito.spy(new BaseService());
        PowerMockito.doReturn("Result").when(basicServiceObj, "save", ... optionalArgs);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSave(){
        testee.save();
    }
}
```

If you are returning nothing (`void`) then instead of `doReturn` you can use `doNothing`. Add some `optionalArgs` if the method have some arguments, if not, then skip that part.

Comment: Is there any suggestion if BasicService is abstract?

Comment: In that case I think you might instantiate testee with line `testee = PowerMockito.spy(new ChildService())` and remove basicServiceObj completely. Also replace basicServiceObj with testee in `when` method argument. Please try it and tell me if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your base class is not public-ed, then Mockito cannot intercept it due to visibility, if you change base class as public, or @Override in sub class (as public), then Mockito can mock it correctly.

```
public class BaseService{
  public boolean foo(){
    return true;
  }
}

public ChildService extends BaseService{
}

@Test
@Mock ChildService childService;
public void testSave() {
  Mockito.when(childService.foo()).thenReturn(false);

  // When
  assertFalse(childService.foo());
}
```

Comment: This is not the point. ChildService should override foo() and the problem is how to mock BaseService.foo() but not ChildService.foo()

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I make a new method to wrap super class's method and make a test double. Because I need result from super class method when I implement oAuth2 client. I want this answer is helpful who someone needs to use result from super class's method.

#### System Under Test

- Make a `loadUserFromParent` method to wrap super class function

```java
package action.in.blog.service;

import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.DefaultOAuth2UserService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class DefaultOAuth2UserServiceDelegator extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {

    private final List<CustomOAuth2UserService> oAuth2UserServices;


    public DefaultOAuth2UserServiceDelegator(List<CustomOAuth2UserService> oAuth2UserServices) {
        this.oAuth2UserServices = oAuth2UserServices;
    }

    public OAuth2User loadUserFromParent(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) {
        return super.loadUser(userRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        for (var oauth2Service : oAuth2UserServices) {
            if (!oauth2Service.supports(userRequest)) {
                continue;
            }
            var oauthUser = loadUserFromParent(userRequest);
            return oauth2Service.createOrLoadUser(oauthUser);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Not found user service");
    }
}
```

#### Test

- Make SUT as a spy
- Use `doReturn(expectedValue).when(testDouble).method(params)`

```java
package action.in.blog.service;

import action.in.blog.domain.CustomAuthentication;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.DefaultOAuth2User;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

class DefaultOAuth2UserServiceDelegatorTest {

    CustomOAuth2UserService googleUserService;
    CustomOAuth2UserService facebookUserService;
    DefaultOAuth2UserServiceDelegator sut;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        googleUserService = mock(CustomOAuth2UserService.class);
        facebookUserService = mock(CustomOAuth2UserService.class);
        sut = spy(new DefaultOAuth2UserServiceDelegator(
                List.of(googleUserService, facebookUserService)
        ));
    }

    @Test
    void loadUser() {

        var authentication = new CustomAuthentication();
        var oauth2UserRequest = mock(OAuth2UserRequest.class);
        var oauth2User = new DefaultOAuth2User(Collections.emptyList(), Map.of("id", "junhyunny"), "id");
        // make a stub 
        doReturn(oauth2User).when(sut).loadUserFromParent(oauth2UserRequest);
        when(googleUserService.supports(oauth2UserRequest)).thenReturn(true);
        when(googleUserService.createOrLoadUser(oauth2User)).thenReturn(authentication);


        var result = sut.loadUser(oauth2UserRequest);


        assertEquals(result, authentication);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is simple approach that works for most of cases. You can spy your object and stub the method you want to mock.

Here is an example:

```
MyClass myObjectSpy = Mockito.spy(myObject);
org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn("yourReturnValue").when(mySpyObject).methodToMock(any()..);
```

So, when you test your object, you can use myObjectSpy and when methodToMock is called, it will overwrite the normal behavior by a mock method.

This code for a method with return. In case you have a void method you can use [doNothing](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.9.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12) instead.

Comment: In this case you are stubbing the subclass' method not the superclass' method.