# How to inject method into java tested class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, junit

How to inject method (using reflection) into super class without extending tested class?
I need to replace  `getExternalData()` to test the logic inside `someMethod()`. I cannot change tested classes - because of that I was thinking about injecting method.

I have flowing classes:

```
public class B extends A{
  public String someMethod(){
    String someString = super.getExternalData();
    //logic to be tested - manipulating on someString
    return someString;
  }
}

public class A{
  public String getExternalData(){
    //some Logic that generates "externalData" string
    return externalData;
  }
}
```

And test:

```
public class CesTest{
  @Test
  public void someMethodTest()(
    B instance = new B();
    //...
    //...
    assertEquals("expectedData", instance.someMethod());
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is you can't without doing some really odd stuff that would result in your not testing the class under test but some odd mocked-out version of the class under test. You need to do whatever setup is required to have `getExternalData` return the appropriate value. That being said, `class A` should be written in such a was that a `mock` could be injected to provide this `external data` without hitting an external resource.

Answer (score 0):

why using

```
super.getExternalData()
```

and not just

```
getExternalData()
```

this will let you extends B and override getExternalData()

Comment: this the way class is writed, cannot change code - just writing unit tests

Comment: In that case you'll have to use AOP or reflection. any way it's gonna be dirty. that's why we say- "if you can't test it- there is something wrong with your design"

Comment: could you extend your comment? How to use reflection or AOP in this case?

Comment: like @Boris Pavlović say: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass

Answer (score 0):

```
public class B extends A{
  public String someMethod(){
    String someString = getExternalData(); //without 'super'
    //logic to be tested - manipulating on someString
    return someString;
  }
  @Override
  public String getExternalData(){
    //Overriding code
    return externalData;
  }
}

public class A{
  public String getExternalData(){
    //some Logic that generates "externalData" string
    return externalData;
  }
}
```

this helped you?

Comment: I cannot change tested classes - because of that I was thinking about injecting method. There is option with extending B class, but I wanted to avoid this if its possible

Answer (score 0):

(sry about my english)

Hi Marcin,

I answered you in Apr 11 at 10:55 but, after i get a junit lesson, i have a better solution, if u arent solved it yet:

Fisrt to All, the TestClass must be called as the SUT (Subject Under Test) with the sufix "Test", in your case, BTest, by convention.

Second, in JUnit is often to use Mock Classes to change Collaborators method (Collaborator is the classes that cause dependence with the SUT). The better choice is use Mockito of Google Code, a Free and the better API of jUnit. Use that:

```
public class BTest{
  @Test
  public void someMethod()(
    B instance = new B();
    when(instance.getExternalData()).thenReturn("expectedData");
    assertEquals("expectedData", instance.someMethod());
  }
}
```

http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html Google Code Rules! If it works vote my answer, thanks