# Mock a parent class to test a wrapper class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class which extends another class I don't own.  My class is used to calculate metrics around a few of the many calls to the parent class.  Is there a way I can mock the parent class in a unit test (while preserving my child's logic) to ensure that calls made against my child always "make it through" to the wrapped parent?

In code

```
Class SlowClass {
    public Object doFoo(Object obj) {
        //...
    }
    public Object doBar(Object obj) {
        //...
    }

    // Many more methods I don't care about.

}

Class SlowClassWrapper extends SlowClass {
    public Object doFoo(Object obj) {
        //...
        Object toReturn = super.doFoo(obj)
        //...
        return toReturn;
    }
    public Object doBar(Object obj) {
        //...
        Object toReturn = super.doFoo(obj)
        //...
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

I want to somehow mock out `SlowClass.doFoo` so that `SlowClassWrapper.doFoo` makes a call to its parent without actually making the call.  I then want to confirm that `obj` got through untouched, and the response from `SlowClass.doFoo` gets back untouched.

Answer (score 4):

In general, this is not something that mocking frameworks can happily do in Java. You might want to consider restructuring your code to use composition instead of inheritance. Then, you could inject the SlowClass instance into the wrapper's constructor, allowing easy testability through regular mocking.

For what it's worth, neither Mockito nor PowerMock can mock out super methods: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass) and [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/powermock/ZgiR8y_P9R4).

Comment: Thanks.  Composition is possible, but the slow library is actively being developed (we pull new versions every few months), and this class has ~60 methods.  Annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like that:

```
public class SlowClassWrapper {
    /** wrapped parent */
    public final SlowClass parent;

    public SlowClassWrapper() {
        this(new SlowClass());

    @VisibleForTesting
    protected SlowClassWrapper(SlowClass parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Object doFoo(Object obj) {
        //...
        Object toReturn = parent.doFoo(obj)
        //...
        return toReturn;
    }

    public Object doBar(Object obj) {
        //...
        Object toReturn = parent.doFoo(obj)
        //...
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Using [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) and JUnit

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SlowClassWrapperTest {
     /** parent mock */
     @Mock
     private SlowClass parentMock;

     /** instance under tests */
     private SlowClassWrapper instance;

     @Before
     public void setUp() {
         this.instance = new SlowClassWrapper(this.parentMock);
     }

     @Test
     public void testDoFoo() {
         final Object obj1 = new Object();
         final Object obj2 = new Object();
         Mockito.doReturn(obj2).when(this.parentMock).doFoo(Matchers.any());
         assertEquals(obj2, this.instance.doFoo(obj1));
         Mockito.verify(this.parentMock).doFoo(obj1);
         Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(this.parentMock);
     }

     @Test
     public void testDoBar() {
         final Object obj1 = new Object();
         final Object obj2 = new Object();
         Mockito.doReturn(obj2).when(this.parentMock).doBar(Matchers.any());
         assertEquals(obj2, this.instance.doBar(obj1);
         Mockito.verify(this.parentMock).doBar(obj1);
         Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(this.parentMock);
     }
}
```

(not tested)

Comment: It is possible with composition, as you demonstrate.  I was hoping for a better approach, but this doesn't appear to exist.