# Powermock - mocking a super method invocation

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, super

Here is my code -

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.*;
import static org.powermock.api.support.SuppressCode.*;

class BaseService {
    public int save() {
        validate();
        return 2;
    }

    public static int save2() {
        return 5;
    }

    public void validate() {
        System.out.println("base service save executing...");
    }
}

class ChildService extends BaseService {
    public int save() {
        System.out.println("child service save executing...");
        int x = super.save2();
        int y = super.save();
        System.out.println("super.save returned " + y);
        load();
        return 1 + x;
    }

    public void load() {
        System.out.println("child service load executing...");
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(BaseService.class)
public class PreventSuperInvocation {

    @Test
    public void testSave() throws Exception {

        org.powermock.api.support.Stubber.stubMethod(BaseService.class,
                "save2", 4);
        suppressMethod(BaseService.class, "save");
        ChildService childService = new ChildService();
        System.out.println(childService.save());
    }

}
```

I would like to mock `super.save()` in `ChildService` class. But I can't find a way of doing it. `suppressMethod()` only suppresses and returns a default value (0 in the above case). And things like `MemberModifier`, `Stubber`, `MethodProxy` only work for static methods.

Is there a way of doing this in Powermock?

I'm using Powermock 1.5 and Mockito 1.9.5.

Comment: For me what this situation tells me is to use composition rather than inheritance! This would probably would to a better OO design as well. So I would not even bother to try to achieve that with powermock, it's like writing legacy code right now !

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass

Comment: Would be interesting (aside from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass) to get a definitive answer on wether PowerMock can do this or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that jMockit can do what I need. Maybe I will I post this question to the powermock mailing list. Meanwhile below should suffice.
package learning_mocking_tools.learning_mocking_tools;
    package learning_mocking_tools.learning_mocking_tools;

```
import mockit.*;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;


class BaseService {
    public int save() {
        validate();
        return 2;
    }

    public static int save2() {
        return 5;
    }

    public void validate() {
        System.out.println("base service save executing...");
    }
}

class ChildService extends BaseService {
    public int save() {
        System.out.println("child service save executing...");
        int x = super.save2();
        int y = super.save();
        System.out.println("super.save returned " + y);
        load();
        return 1 + y;
    }

    public void load() {
        System.out.println("child service load executing...");
    }
}

@MockClass(realClass = BaseService.class)
class MockBase {

    @Mock
    public int save() {
        System.out.println("mocked base");
        return 9;
    }
}

public class PreventSuperInvocation {

    @Test
    public void testSave() throws Exception {
        MockBase mockBase = new MockBase();
        Mockit.setUpMock(BaseService.class, mockBase);

        ChildService childService = new ChildService();
//      int x = childService.save();

        Assert.assertEquals(9 + 1, childService.save());

        Mockit.tearDownMocks();
    }

}
```

Comment: NB. jMockit removed the @MockClass(realClass) annotation in version 1.4 (since Aug '13.)