# Verifying super.method() is called using Mockito

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, super

First of all I would like to say I am working with legacy code and I cannot change it no matter how much I want to.

With that out the way, what I am trying to do is verify that a super.method() is called. This is specifically what I am trying to test with Mockito/Junit:

```
class foo extends JApplet(){

       public void destroy(){
          super.destroy();
 }
}
```

Normally something like this would suffice in a test case if it was not a super method being called:

```
verify(foo).destroy();
```

I've seen this question asked a couple of times and usually the response is "Inheritance is bad, change your code" which I cannot do at all unfortunately. Is anyone aware of any frameworks or small little tricks I could do to test this?

Thanks in advance - I know this is a tricky problem!

Comment: Small little tricks for testing?  Can you TEMPORARILY change your code? Print something to the console inside super.destroy().  Do you have access to the source?

Comment: Changing the source code is completely out the question unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

You can refactor the code to call the super method in some other method like:

```
      class foo extends JApplet(){

       public void destroy(){
          callSuperDestroy();
       }
       public void callSuperDestroy(){
           super.destroy();
       }}
```

And then verify:

```
verify(foo).callSuperDestroy();
```

Comment: This is not helpful. In my opinion, you should verify the call to a method once you know that that method is already tested. If one verifies the call to `callSuperDestroy` must then test also `callSuperDestroy`, which may be as expensive as doing it inside the original design.

Comment: This was the only way in which I could verify the order of invocations on a spy where one of the invocations called the super method from the override of that method.

Comment: This is the way we do it at work. Sometimes we need to refactor some code in order to make it testable.

Comment: but then you would end up with not verifying that super is called into callSuperDestroy

Answer (score 3):

It appears that JMockit might be able to do this. Check out this post:

[Powermock - mocking a super method invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125774/powermock-mocking-a-super-method-invocation)

Answer (score 3):

What you actually need to test is that the *effect* of invoking the super-method still hold true. The fact that the easiest way to achieve this is via invoking the super-method is simply a design detail.

With this in mind:

1. Write a test for the super-method.
2. Write a test for your sub-method, and also invoke the test for the super-method on the same class from within this test (either by direct invocation, or by subclassing the test).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but isn't it possible to create a custom ClassLoader which overrides loading of JApplet class only? Then you can create your own JApplet, which remembers whether destroy() is called.

Comment: Try John B's answer first - seems much better than my suggestion :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was planning to do - but I was unsure if there was a custom ClassLoader application out there. Was planning to manually edit the applet.java and get eclipse to point to it instead. 

Easier said then done of course and I will have a look at powermock first.