# How to verify parent class method invocation of super.method()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, mockito

I need to verify `super.method(1)` method invocation. Here is my code:

```
public class X extends Y {

    @Override
    void method(String s) {
        super.method(1);
    }

    @Override
    void method(int i) {
        super.method("str");
    }
}

public class Y {

    void method(String s) {
        // do some action
    }

    void method(int i) {
        // do some action
    }
}
```

And incorrect working test

```
public class XTest {

    @Test
    public void should_also_invoke_parent_method_with_proper_param() {

        // Given
        X spy = Mockito.spy(new X());

        // When
        spy.method("str");

        // Than
        Mockito.verify((Y) spy).method(1);
    }
}
```

How can I verify `super.method(1)` invocation?

Comment: @AnkurShanbhag If downvoting comments was possible I'd make a separate account to do it twice for yours...

Comment: I think the only way you can do this is to have some side effects in the super classes method which you can detect from the derived class. Like say, initialize a field or modify a value... etc.

Comment: @Aaron are you restricted to using Mockito only? Or you may use other frameworks like PowerMock or JMockit?

Comment: Yes. I can't use JMockit. Only Mockito or its extensions (e.g. PowerMock, EasyMock).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can re-factor the code to call the super method from some other method

```
    public class X extends Y {

    @Override
    void method(String s) {
        callsuperMethod();
    }
    void callsuperMethod(){
        super.method(1);
    }

    @Override
    void method(int i) {
        super.method("str");
    }
}
```

now you can verify

```
 Mockito.verify(spy).callsuperMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use JMockito. This post can be useful to you.

[Powermock - mocking a super method invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125774/powermock-mocking-a-super-method-invocation)