# verify the super class method is called

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
class BaseService {
    public void print(String msg) {
       //something
    }
}

class ChildService extends BaseService {
    @Override
    public void print(String msg) {
        super.print(msg)
    }
}
```

I am trying to write junit test to verify that super class method is called. Tried few threads with similar questions but not seem to close to this.
One example is

```
        BaseService classToTest = Mockito.spy(new BaseService();
        Mockito.doNothing().when((ChildService)classToTest).print("test message");
        classToTest.print("test message");
        verify(classToTest).print("test message");
```

but this is not verifying the super class method call but verifying the base class call

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to be possible, other than by verifying any effects of the base class methods.

Comment: Would this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896636/how-to-verify-invocation-of-super-method-of-parent-class
they are calling the super method using a separate method so Mockito can spy.

Comment: @SanuraHettiarachchi I found that before but didn't help in my case as I have to test the protected method which gets me the same issue

Comment: As @LouisWasserman already said, I would strongly recommend to test behaviour, not implementation. In general, we should not car *what* is called, as long as the behaviour is correct.