# How to make a mock of a super method (with return)

Tags: java, junit, mockito, easymock, jmockit

Is possible make a mock of the method of a super class? (not overwritten)

```java
public class FooBarTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Bar bar = Mockito.spy(new Bar());
        Mockito.doReturn("Mock!").when((Foo) bar).test();

        String actual = bar.test(); // returns only "Mock!"
        assertEquals("Mock! Bar!", actual);
    }

    public static class Foo {
        public String test(){
            return "Foo!";
        }
    }

    public static class Bar extends Foo {
        @Override
        public String test(){
            return super.test()+" Bar!";
        }
    }
}
```

Off: how to highlight code here?

Comment: Alternatively, tag question with Java, and it should do it automatically.

Comment: lmgtfy: [Mockito How to mock only the call of a method of the superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution, using the JMockit mocking API:

```
public class FooBarTest
{
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        final Bar bar = new Bar();
        new NonStrictExpectations(Foo.class) {{ bar.test(); result = "Mock!"; }};

        String actual = bar.test();
        assertEquals("Mock! Bar!", actual);
    }

    public static class Foo {
        public String test() { return "Foo!"; }
    }

    public static class Bar extends Foo {
        @Override
        public String test() { return super.test() + " Bar!"; }
    }
}
```