# Mocking methods from subclass while unit testing class methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to write a unit test for a particular method of a class - `foo`. This class extends another class - `bar`, which is inside an external jar.
The problem is that this base `bar` has some methods to interact with database, which I don't want to actually call.
I tried creating a mock of this base class foo, but this doesn't work. It actually tries to connect to the database instead of mocking.

```
@Test
public void testSomeMethod(){
bar b= mock(bar.class);
when(b.calldatabase()).thenReturn(resultset); //calldatabse is in base class bar

//create expected object, and set properties here
Results expected = new Results();
expectedResult = foo.MethodUnderTest(); // this has call to calldatabase and then uses resultset mocked above
assert()...
}
```

I am using JUnit4 with Mockito. 
Is it really possible to it like this-- mocking methods in base class but actually testing the derived class? If not, how can I test this?
I can have the base class changed if required, and use any other tool/library as needed.

Comment: Take a look at this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass

Comment: Thanks gkamal! The chosen answer was not much of help for the particular problem I am facing, but one of the other answers helped :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mocked an instance of Bar, but this mocked Bar is never used in your test, since you test a separate instance: foo. Creating a mock Bar instance creates an object of a new, dynamically generated class, which overrides all the methods of the the Bar class. It doesn't change the internal byte-code of the methods in the Bar class.

What you need is a Spy, or a partial mock:

```
Foo partiallyMockedFoo = spy(new Foo());

// stub the doSomethingWithTheDatabase()
when(partiallyMockedFoo.doSomethingWithTheDatabase()).thenReturn("1234"); 

// call the real method, that internally calls doSomethingWithTheDatabase()
partiallyMockedFoo.methodUnderTest();
```

Comment: This is perfect!spy combined with mock objects resolved the issue. Thanks!