# Mockito - Mock base implementation while testing derived class implementation of same method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am using Mockito for some unit testing. I have the following classes:

```
public class Base {
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("Base"); // some work in the base class
    }
}

public class Derived extends Base {
    @Override
    public void say() {
        super.say();   // do the base class work
        System.out.println("Derived"); // some additional work in the derived class
    }
}
```

Now I want to test the Derived class's `say()` method while mocking the base say() method. I followed the suggestion here: [Mockito How to mock only the call of a method of the superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838664/715769) and I now have.

```
public class DerivedTest {
    @Test
    public void testSay() {
        Derived obj = Mockito.spy(new Derived());
        Mockito.doNothing().when((Base)obj).say();
        obj.say();
        // assert only "Derived" was output
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work as it mocks both the base and the derived class implementation. I want to test just the extra logic in the derived class.

How can I do this.

**Update: My solution**

Since I couldn't change the base class as suggested, I modified my derived class to extract all the extra logic in a a separate method and just tested that method.

```
public class Derived extends Base {
    @Override
    public void say() {
        super.say();   // do the base class work
        doAdditionalWork();  // some additional work in the derived class
    }

    void doAdditionalWork() {
        System.out.println("Derived");
    }
}

public class DerivedTest {
    @Test
    public void testDoAdditionalWork() {
        Derived obj = new Derived();
        obj.doAdditionalWork();
        // assert only "Derived" was output
    }
}
```

This means that I am still not testing the derived say() method but given that the logic there is quite simple now, I hope I can be excused for this. The other downside is that I can't have a visibility stricter than package-private for the doAdditionalWork() method.

Answer (score 3):

When you `spy` an object, you completely replace the implementation of the method(s) which you've defined a mock behavior for. So, as you noted in the question, this would not work.

One trick around this is to extract an `additionalBehavior()` method, and test it only, without spying or mocking:

```
public class Base {
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("Base"); // some work in the base class
        additionalBehavior();
    }

    protected void additionalBehavior() {
        // No implementation. Alternatively - make it abstract
    }
}

public class Derived extends Base {
    @Override
    protected void additionalBehavior() {
        System.out.println("Derived"); // some additional work in the derived class
    }
}

public class DerivedTest {
    @Test
    public void testAdditionalBehavior() {
        Derived obj = new Derived();
        obj.additioanlBehavior();
        // assert that "Derived" was the output
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I really can't change the base class here.

Comment: That is the problem here. You can only mock loose couplings; inheritance, by definition, is a tight coupling between types. Do you absolutely need to inherit from `Base`, or is there a common interface that `Derived` can implement? If there is, you could use the Decorator pattern to achieve the necessary loose coupling.