# How to mock super reference (on super class)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, super, powermock

Sometimes when I write unit tests I should to mock reference to superclass.

I have read this question:
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass)

This answer [answer with DI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3479507/2674303) advice to refactor code. But I cannot it

this answer [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838664/2674303) is not suitable if superclass method is enough big. In my case I have very big code. Yes I know that it is brokes SOLID OOD principes but I just should to write test. I have not enough time for refactor.

said question was asked 4 years ago!

Does currently Mockito or Powermock can resolve this issue ?

### update

code example:

```
class BaseService {  
    public void save() {
      // a lot of code here! I cannot change this code.
    }  
}

public Childservice extends BaseService {  
    public void save(){  
        //logic for testing
        super.save();
       //logic for testing
    }  
}
```

### update 2

```
public class Parent {
    public int save() {
         return 99;
    }   
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public int save() {
        int i = super.save();
        return i*2;
    }
}
```

and test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Parent.class)
public class ParentTest {
    @Test
    public void testSave() {       
        PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.methodsDeclaredIn(Parent.class));        
        System.out.println(new Child().save());
    }
}
```

output: 198

Comment: Can you make up a code sample to be tested? It would help answering your question.

Comment: @Gábor Lipták please read update

Comment: Can you tell me why your problems cannot be solved by the answer with the solution "DI"? Is there any special things in your code?

Comment: I just cannot change this code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Powermock you can replace or suppress methods, so it is possible to change the action done by `BaseService.save()`. You can also make methods to do nothing with suppressing. You can even suppress static initializer blocks.

Please read [this blog entry of the Powermock authors](http://www.jayway.com/2013/03/05/beyond-mocking-with-powermock/). See chapter "Replacing".

UPDATE:

Suppress seems to work for me, but replace not. See the picture below:
[image]

Comment: about replacing: **Note that this only works for static methods!**

Comment: You can put the super.save to a new method Childservice.callSuperSave(), and you can call ChildService.callSuperSave() from the ChildService.save(), then you can spy on Childservice, and you can suppress or change callSuperSave(). Of course you need then possibility to change the code of ChildService,

Comment: yes your advise can help but it is not that I want.

Comment: Have you prepared the base class, and do you run the test with Powermockrunner?

Comment: Suppress works. See update. If you want, I send you the project zipped, but still everything is visible in the picture.

Comment: 1. please to execute code from my update 2. please give me zip of your archive.

Comment: Maybe you use old version: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=51

Comment: -really problem with version

Comment: I used 1.4.10 powermock. It is work from 1.5 at least

Comment: Try to play with versions)) I think if you write about it in answer - it would awesome. But I have 1 more question. at this case we just supress super method invocation and get default value. Can we set especial begaviour - for example return 9999

Comment: I think if you suppress methods, then the return value is always the java default. So 0 for numbers, false for boolean, null for objects.

Comment: my initial desire - can replace super method, not just supress because  you can get NullPoinerException sometimes

Comment: @gstackoverflow did you find a solution for overriding instead of suppressing?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not mocking super reference but I think it is helpful for someone who wants to make test double parent's method.

In my case, I make a new method to wrap super class's method and make a test double. Because I need result from super class method when I implement oAuth2 client. I want this answer is helpful who someone needs to use result from super class's method.

#### System Under Test

- Make a `loadUserFromParent` method to wrap super class function

```java
package action.in.blog.service;

import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.DefaultOAuth2UserService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class DefaultOAuth2UserServiceDelegator extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {

    private final List<CustomOAuth2UserService> oAuth2UserServices;


    public DefaultOAuth2UserServiceDelegator(List<CustomOAuth2UserService> oAuth2UserServices) {
        this.oAuth2UserServices = oAuth2UserServices;
    }

    public OAuth2User loadUserFromParent(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) {
        return super.loadUser(userRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        for (var oauth2Service : oAuth2UserServices) {
            if (!oauth2Service.supports(userRequest)) {
                continue;
            }
            var oauthUser = loadUserFromParent(userRequest);
            return oauth2Service.createOrLoadUser(oauthUser);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Not found user service");
    }
}
```

#### Test

- Make SUT as a spy
- Use `doReturn(expectedValue).when(testDouble).method(params)`

```java
package action.in.blog.service;

import action.in.blog.domain.CustomAuthentication;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.DefaultOAuth2User;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

class DefaultOAuth2UserServiceDelegatorTest {

    CustomOAuth2UserService googleUserService;
    CustomOAuth2UserService facebookUserService;
    DefaultOAuth2UserServiceDelegator sut;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        googleUserService = mock(CustomOAuth2UserService.class);
        facebookUserService = mock(CustomOAuth2UserService.class);
        sut = spy(new DefaultOAuth2UserServiceDelegator(
                List.of(googleUserService, facebookUserService)
        ));
    }

    @Test
    void loadUser() {

        var authentication = new CustomAuthentication();
        var oauth2UserRequest = mock(OAuth2UserRequest.class);
        var oauth2User = new DefaultOAuth2User(Collections.emptyList(), Map.of("id", "junhyunny"), "id");
        // make a stub 
        doReturn(oauth2User).when(sut).loadUserFromParent(oauth2UserRequest);
        when(googleUserService.supports(oauth2UserRequest)).thenReturn(true);
        when(googleUserService.createOrLoadUser(oauth2User)).thenReturn(authentication);


        var result = sut.loadUser(oauth2UserRequest);


        assertEquals(result, authentication);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is impossible; the whole point of a superclass is that it encapsulates upstream state and functionality, and the class hierarchy is hard-coded in your subclass based on the `extends` relationship.

Comment: Now Powermock can make very hard things with bytecode. I am not wondering if it is possible.