# How to mock super class method using Mockito or any other relevant java framework

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

My Scenario is as below

```
class SuperClass{
   public void run(){
      System.out.println("I am running in Super class");
   }
}

class ChildClass extends SuperClass{
  public void childRunner(){
     System.out.println("Step 1");
     System.out.println("Step 2");
     **run();**
     System.out.println("Last Step");
  }
}
```

Now I want to test the `childRunner()` method of `ChildClass` and since this method internally calls the super class method, i need some help/piece of code on how to mock the `run()` method which is present in `SuperClass`.

Answer (score 22):

Ideally, you should "favor composition over inheritance".

If you don't have this option you could use `doNothing` which basically tells Mockito to do nothing when a method in a mock/spy object is called. This was also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass)

Following code example should help

```
@Test
public void tst() {
    ChildClass ch = Mockito.spy(new ChildClass());
    Mockito.doNothing().when((SuperClass)ch).run();
    ch.childRunner();

}

class SuperClass{
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("I am running in Super class");
    }
}

class ChildClass extends SuperClass{
    public void childRunner(){
        System.out.println("Step 1");
        run();
        System.out.println("Last Step");
    }
}
```

output:

```
Step 1
Last Step
```

In case you use super.run(); this won't work

Comment: What if the super class method returns a value which is used in the child class?

Comment: What do to if we use super.run() method

Comment: @PankajRathi I think you can achieve that only using PowerMockito

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example for a class that extends another class and it has some other dependencies. In this case, I'll move the superclass call into the other method and then mock the superclass caller method.

```
class Child extends Parent {

  @Autowired
  private Dependicy d;

  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) {
    the code to be tested...
    superAuthenticate(auth);// the code that I don't want to deal with it.
    return auth;
  }

  protected Authentication superAuthenticate(Authentication auth) {
    return super.authenticate(auth);
  }
}
```

As you can see above, the authenticate method does some logic and then call the super class's method, so I want to mock the superclass call and test my own code block. Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ChildTest {
    @Mock
    private Dependicy d;
    @InjectMocks
    private Child child = new Child();

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        Child spy = Mockito.spy(child);

        when(d.aMethod(aParam)).thenReturn(aResult);
        doReturn(usefulResult).when(spy).superAuthenticate(any());

        Authentication result = spy.authenticate(auth);
        assertThat(result).isNotNull;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have already answered for suppressing superclass method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass/66584523#66584523) but according to your question I am updating the code as below

I found a way to suppress the superclass method using PowerMockito. 3 simple steps need for this

1. Use **PowerMockito.suppress** method and **MemberMatcher.methodsDeclaredIn** method to supress parent class method
2. Second **add Parent class in @PrepareForTest**
3. Run your test class with PowerMock ie add **@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)** above your test class.

   ```
   @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
   @PrepareForTest({SuperClass.class})
   public class TestChildClass(){

       @Spy
       private ChildClass testChildClassObj = Mockito.spy(new ChildClass());

       @Test
       public void testChildRunner(){
           PowerMockito.suppress(MemberMatcher.methodsDeclaredIn(SuperClass.class));

           //your further test code

           testChildClassObj.childRunner();
       }
   }
   ```

Note: This will work only when the superclass method does not return anything.

Answer (score -1):

As a quick way around, I just added a different proxy method on the subclass that calls super's run. Then you can mock the "proxy".