# Mockito's when() isn't stubbing superclass's method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have 'MyClass' inheriting from 'BaseClass' with a method `doBaseStuff()` that isn't overloaded:

```
public class BaseClass {
    public String doBaseStuff(String var1, String var2) {
        //Do something
        return someStringValue;
    }

public class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    public String doMyStuff(String var1, String var2) {
        //Do some stuffs
        doBaseStuff(var1, var2);
        //Do more stuffs
        return someStringValue;
    }
}
```

Then I have a test case for `MyClass`:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @InjectMocks
    MyClass myClass;

    public void testDoOtherThing() {
        // Some setups
        when(myClass.doBaseStuff(dummyVar1, dummyVar2))
                .thenReturn("This isn't catching the invocation!");

        myClass.doMyStuff(dummyVar1, dummyVar2);

        // Some verify statements
    }
}
```

However, `when`/`then` statement for `doBaseStuff()` is not mocking the behaviour whenever that method is invoked.

As a (very shitty) workaround, I can declare a separate `BaseClass` object as a member of `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    private Baseclass baseClass;

    ...

         baseClass.doBaseStuff(var1, var2);

    ...

}

public class MyClassTest {
    @InjectMocks
    MyClass myClass;
    @Mock
    BaseClass baseClass;

    ...

    when(baseClass.doBaseStuff(dummyVar1, dummyVar2))
            .thenReturn("This technically works, but ugh...");

    ...

}
```

However, `MyClass` one of the subclasses of `BaseClass` shares common functionality.

Is there any way for `MyClass` mock to be aware of `doBaseStuff()` implementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock super class method using Mockito or anyother relavent java framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319580/how-to-mock-super-class-method-using-mockito-or-anyother-relavent-java-framework)

Comment: `myClass` is not a mock, so you can't stub its methods. https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.27.0/index.html?org/mockito/Spy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `@Spy` instead:

```java
@Spy
MyClass myClass;
```

The difference between a mock and a spy is well answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295625/mockito-spy-vs-mock).

Also, `when().thenReturn()` method will acually execute the real method. Only the return value is substituted. If you don't want to execute the original method, use `doReturn().when()` syntax instead:

```
doReturn("This technically works, but ugh...").when(myClass).doBaseStuff(dummyVar1, dummyVar2);
```