# How to call super class method correctly from Mockito Junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a base handler

```
public class BaseHandler {
    protected Object extractInput(RoutingContext rc) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.put("baseKey", "baseValue");
        return jsonObject
    }
}
```

And a child handler

```
public class ChildHandler extends BaseHandler {

    @Override
    protected Object extractInput(RoutingContext rc) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) super.extractInput(rc);
        populateFileObjects(rc).ifPresent(jsonArray -> json.put("fileUploads", jsonArray));
        return jsonObject
    }
}
```

I have written the Junit code using Mockito

```
@Test
public void extractInputTest() {
    ChildHandler handler = spy(new ChildHandler());
    RoutingContext rc = mock(RoutingContext.class);

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.put("key", "value");

    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    JsonObject fileObject = new JsonObject();
    fileObject.put("fileName", "name");
    jsonArray.add(fileObject);
    Optional<JsonArray> optional = Optional.of(jsonArray);

    doReturn(jsonObject).when((BaseHandler)handler).extractInput(eq(rc));
    doReturn(optional).when(handler).populateFileObjects(rc);

    Object o = handler.extractInput(rc);
    Map<String, Object> map = ((JsonObject) o).getMap();

    Assert.assertEquals("value", ((JsonObject)o).getString("key"));
    Assert.assertEquals(2, map.size()); //Junit fails here
    Assert.assertEquals(JsonArray.class, map.get("fileUploads").getClass());
    Assert.assertEquals(fileObject, ((JsonArray)map.get("fileUploads")).getJsonObject(0));
}
```

I tried putting breakpoint on the first line of ChildHandler class's extractInput method and observed that it was never called.

What is the correct way of mocking super.method calls ?

Comment: perhaps this helps you on your way? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319580/how-to-mock-super-class-method-using-mockito-or-anyother-relavent-java-framework

Comment: @Paul - I am doing similar to what they suggested in that post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way of doing it, but it is not very clean, but it's better than doing same dirty stuff with Java Reflection. You should extract the call to the super method in another method in your child class, like:

```
public class ChildHandler extends BaseHandler {

    @Override
    protected Object extractInput(RoutingContext rc) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) superExtractInput(rc);
        populateFileObjects(rc).ifPresent(jsonArray -> json.put("fileUploads", jsonArray));
        return jsonObject
    }

    protected Object superExtractInput(RoutingContext rc){
        super.extractInput(rc);
    }
}
```

And your test would look like:

```
@Test
public void extractInputTest() {
    ChildHandler handler = spy(new ChildHandler());
    RoutingContext rc = mock(RoutingContext.class);

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.put("key", "value");

    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    JsonObject fileObject = new JsonObject();
    fileObject.put("fileName", "name");
    jsonArray.add(fileObject);
    Optional<JsonArray> optional = Optional.of(jsonArray);

    doReturn(jsonObject).when(handler).superExtractInput(eq(rc));
    doReturn(optional).when(handler).populateFileObjects(rc);

    Object o = handler.extractInput(rc);
    Map<String, Object> map = ((JsonObject) o).getMap();

    Assert.assertEquals("value", ((JsonObject)o).getString("key"));
    Assert.assertEquals(2, map.size()); //Junit fails here
    Assert.assertEquals(JsonArray.class, map.get("fileUploads").getClass());
    Assert.assertEquals(fileObject, ((JsonArray)map.get("fileUploads")).getJsonObject(0));
}
```

---

It would be better to [favor composition over inheritance](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/06/why-favor-composition-over-inheritance-java-oops-design.html), for avoiding this kind of problems during testing phase.

The classes would be like:

```
public class BaseHandler {
    protected Object extractInput(RoutingContext rc) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.put("baseKey", "baseValue");
        return jsonObject
    }
}

public class ChildHandler{

    private final BaseHandler baseHandler;

    public ChildHandler(final BaseHandler baseHandler){
        this.baseHandler = baseHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object extractInput(RoutingContext rc) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) baseHandler.extractInput(rc);
        populateFileObjects(rc).ifPresent(jsonArray -> json.put("fileUploads", jsonArray));
        return jsonObject
    }
}
```

And the test would be much more clear:

```
@InjectMocks
ChildHandler testObj;

@Mock
BaseHandler baseHandlerMock;

@Mock
RoutingContext routingContextMock;

@Test
public void extractInputTest() {
    
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.put("key", "value");

    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    JsonObject fileObject = new JsonObject();
    fileObject.put("fileName", "name");
    jsonArray.add(fileObject);
    Optional<JsonArray> optional = Optional.of(jsonArray);

    when(baseHandlerMock.extractInput(routingContextMock)).thenReturn(routingContextMock);
    doReturn(optional).when(handler).populateFileObjects(routingContextMock);

    Object o = handler.extractInput(routingContextMock);
    Map<String, Object> map = ((JsonObject) o).getMap();

    Assert.assertEquals("value", ((JsonObject)o).getString("key"));
    Assert.assertEquals(2, map.size()); //Junit fails here
    Assert.assertEquals(JsonArray.class, map.get("fileUploads").getClass());
    Assert.assertEquals(fileObject, ((JsonArray)map.get("fileUploads")).getJsonObject(0));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Extracting the super method out and stubbing it does the trick.
in the answer you should replace super.extractInput to superExtractInput