# How mock public or protected method inherited from a superclass?

Tags: mocking, mockito, powermock

The code below shows a method to be tested in the class `Sub` - Therefore
I do not require to mock the class `Sub`. However I'd like to mock the
`Super` class and the `getSuperData` method. Is there a way of doing this using 
Mockito/Powermock?
I'd also like to know if there's a way of mocking the `Super` constructor?
Thanks,
Steve

```
public class Super {
    private String data;
    public Super() {
    }
    public String getSuperData() {
        return data;
    }
}

public class Sub extends Super {
    Sub() {
        super();
    }
    public String methodToTest() {
        ...
        String data = getSuperData();
        ...
    }
}

public class TestSub {
    Sub sub = new Sub();
    Super superMock = Mockito.mock(Super.class);
    Mockito.when(superMock.getSuperData()).thenReturn("data");
}
```

Comment: Have a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it requires you to spy on your object:

```
public class TestSub {
    Sub sub = Mockito.spy(Sub.class);
    Mockito.when(superMock.getSuperData()).thenReturn("data");
    sub.methodToTest();
}
```

This way you mocked away the super method, as a spy allows you to mock methods. However the advantage of a spy is that for unmocked methods, it will call the real implementation. Therefore the `sub.methodToTest()` call will still invoke the real implementation.

As for your second sub-question, I know PowerMock is able to mock a constructor, but I am not sure if in this context it would be possible. If you would want to mock certain statements in a constructor, it might be better to delegate those to a new method and then mock this method.