# How to test protected method is called or not in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

This is a base class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
  {
    protected void demoMethod()
    {
     //to Do
    }
  }
```

I want to test whether `demoMethd()` in sub class is called or not using `Mockito`.
I tried with  `Mockito.verify` but call goes to sub class method but i want to super method to be called.Is there any solution to test whether `super.demoMethod()` is called or not. Code is given as below:

```
 public class SubClass extends BaseClass
{
  @Override
  protected void demoMethod()
  {
    if( true)
   {
    return;
    }
   super.demoMethod();
  }
 }
```

Comment: suppose if there is some code then..i have posted just an demo example

Comment: Post a realistic example. What does the base class really do. What does the subclass really do? The base class method must have side effects (since it returns nothing). The side effects are what you should verify.

Comment: Show  the code of your testclass

Comment: You might be looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3838664/2254048).

Comment: assume base class method having some code..now how can i test whether super.demoMethod is called or not?

Comment: @YoungHobbit but your methods are public and mines are protected

Comment: @Jens Mockito.verify( (BaseClass) subClassObject, Mockito.times( 1 ) ).demoMethod();  this code i have tried but its not possible as demoMethod() is protected.Its giving me error as this method is not available

Answer (score 0):

According to me we can not call to protected method in Test class so therefore the things which i wanted is not possible for this case.