# Mocking Superclass method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to test a class, which extends a superclass. I use JUnit and Mockito. In one method this class calls a supermethod of the superclass:

```
@Override
public void init(String input){
    super.init();
    ...
}
```

Now in my test-class I already have following setup:

```
@InjectMocks
private MyClass classUnderTest = new MyClass();

@Before
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Now how do I mock the `super.method` call? I don't think Spying will help in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mockito How to mock only the call of a method of the superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass)

Comment: I think mockito cannot help you there - the question is asked here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be mocking this call. You should not have inheritance here at all. If class `A` needs to call method `b()` which is tested elsewhere and you don't care about what it does, it means that method `b()` should be in class `B` which is a dependency of class `A` - and then you can do dependency injection and mock `B`.

If this is some legacy code that you cannot change, one of interesting strategies of refactoring it is making a new method in class `A` and overriding it in your test (by either extending `A` or spying on this method):

```
class A extends B {
    private void b() {
        // something here
        super_b();
    }
    protected void super_b() {
        super.b();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But is it possible to use InjectMocks and Spy on the same class?

Comment: I am not sure how it is related. Dependencies are mocked while you spy on the object under test. By the way, `@InjectMocks` is not recommended - dependencies should not be visible outside the class and it should not be possible to change them.

Comment: Ok, so you would recommend just using Spy instead of InjectMocks?

Comment: Let me repeat - `spy()` method and `@InjectMocks` annotation are not related. Former is used to verify/mock methods of the object you are testing, latter is used to verify/mock methods of the collaborators/dependencies of the object under test.