# Spock mock the parent class method

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock

I have a method which looks like this

```
public class BookItemReader extends StaxEventItemReader<Book> {
   protected List<Book> doRead() {
    List<Book> bookList= null;
    try {
        bookList = convertToBookImport((Book) super.doRead());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //do nothign
    }
    return bookList;
   }
}
```

For the above method, I am trying write a test by mocking the method `super.doRead()`

```
StaxEventItemReader<Book> staxEventItemReader = Spy(StaxEventItemReader) 
staxEventItemReader.doRead() >> new Book()
```

But, the control is invoking the super class method `doRead` . Can someone guide me to mock this `super` class method, so that I can stop invoking the super class method in test?

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838664/2534236) , but the mock is referring to child class method.

```
BookItemReader reader = Mockito.spy(new BookItemReader ())
Mockito.doReturn(new Book()).when((StaxEventItemReader) reader).doRead()
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example (even failing spec)? I'd be much easier to answer/suggest something.

Comment: I have same problem as you :| did you solve this?

Comment: @MarcinLagowski could you please provide a SSCCE that reproduces the problem?