# Mocking super class method

Tags: java, mockito

How to mock super method call from mocked method

```
public class A extends B{

  @Override  
  public retrieveData(){

    //some action here

    super.retrieveData();
  }
}

abstract class B extends C{
  //init super fields here
}

public class C{
  public String retrieveData(){
    //some return
  }

}

Public Atest{
  @InjectMock
  A a;

  @Mock
  C parent; //also tryed for B but the same effect

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void testDetailsRetrievePageList(){
  when(parent.retrieveData()).thenReturn("stub");
  String s = a.retrieveListData();  
    Assert.assertEquals("stub", s);
  }
```

}

Didn't help [Mockito How to mock only the call of a method of the superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass) and post like that.

everytime my super is null in A class

Comment: A extends B that extends C. Your mock try to inject an instance of B / C into A, but A doesn't have a property for this, so it does nothing with your mock. Look here for the solution : http://blog.jdriven.com/2013/05/mock-superclass-method-with-mockito/

Comment: Mockito.when(((C)a).retrieveData()).thenReturn("stub"); but the same error. its seems i stubbed instance of parent class (C)