# Mockito calls real method from superclass when stubbing

Tags: java, unit-testing, inheritance, mockito

I am getting problem with Mockito trying to call real method while stubbing. I assume this might be related to that method is inherited.
This is component external to my system and can't do really much about it. But let's get to the code

```
AbstractRpcClient abstractRpcClient = mock(AbstractRpcClient.class);
doNothing().when(abstractRpcClient).callOnce(anyString(), anyVararg());
```

Since `callOnce` calls methods on some other objects I get NPE right in the second line.
`AbstractRpcClient` inherits from another abstract class, but this class is package local, so I can't even cast it in my stubbing.

Is there anything I can do about it? How can I stub this method to do nothing or throw exception WITHOUT calling real method.

Do I have to extend this class in test and override method `callOnce`? This of course works, but is there any other solution?

Minimal example:

```
package external.component;

public abstract class ClassToMock extends SuperClass {

}


abstract class SuperClass {
    public void callOnce(String method, Object... params) {
        throw new RuntimeException("We shouldn't be here");
    }
}
```

Test class

```
package mypackage

import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyVararg;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class Testclass {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        external.component.ClassToMock classToMock = mock(external.component.ClassToMock.class);
        doNothing().when(classToMock).callOnce(anyString(), anyVararg());
    }

}
```

In example of course `RuntimeException` is thrown from `callOnce` method.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The method shouldn't be called here.

Comment: I recommend you take a look at this thread discussing the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass

Comment: The issue might be because `external.component.ClassToMock` is abstract

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem if superclass wasn't package local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like bug in Mockito and actually it was already reported and was supposed to be fixed over a year ago:

https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/168

I am getting the same (broken) behaviour in versions 1.9.5 and most recent 1.10.19.

I would recommend that you raise the bug with Mockito.

As a temporary work-around there are a few options:

- make the class public
- add `public void callOnce() { super.callOnce(); }` in the child class

Comment: Thanks for info. It looks like it is in 2.0 milestone. Both classes are from external component, but I've just created another subclass that overrides this method.