# How do I mock a method of a super class by Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I need to mock a call to the findById method of the GenericService.

I've this:

```java
public class UserServiceImpl extends GenericServiceImpl<User Integer> implements UserService, Serializable {

.... 
// This call i want mock
user = findById(user.getId());
.....
// For example this one calls mockeo well. Why is not it a call to the generic service?
book = bookService.findById(id);
```

The problem is in the first mock since it is a call to a generic service.

The second mock works fine as well

```
when(bookService.findById(anyInt())).thenReturn(mockedBook);
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of the error the unit test throws? It usually gives a good hint of the issue, i suspect you're calling the mocked findById() method multiple times, but mockito hasn't been told this.

Comment: This is the error stack stack that throws the unit test:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sampleCode.services.service.impl.GenericServiceImpl.findById(GenericServiceImpl.java:28)
 at com.sampleCode.services.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.acceptUser(UserServiceImpl.java:1438)
 at com.sampleCode.services.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.accept(UserServiceImpl.java:1421)
 at com.sampleCode.services.UserServiceTest.testAccept(UserServiceTest.java:277)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
`...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You are actually trying to mock the super class implementation, sounds of a bad design.
 If you cannot refactor, you can use Powermock

try looking at this post: [Mockito How to mock only the call of a method of the superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass) 
It might help

Answer (score 8):

Here is one example I found that resolved same issue in my case-

```
public class BaseController {

     public void method() {
          validate(); // I don't want to run this!
     }
}
public class JDrivenController extends BaseController {
    public void method(){
        super.method()
        load(); // I only want to test this!
    }
}

@Test
public void testSave() {
    JDrivenController spy = Mockito.spy(new JDrivenController());

    // Prevent/stub logic in super.method()
    Mockito.doNothing().when((BaseController)spy).validate();

    // When
    spy.method();

    // Then
    verify(spy).load();
}
```

Comment: a very good answer! +1 for this!

Answer (score 3):

Create a spy of the UserServiceImpl class:
http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy

A spy is a wrapper around an object for which you are still able to define behavior, e.g. stubbing the *findById()* method of the super class, but unlike a mock, non-stubbed methods still call their real implementation.

```
class GenericServiceImpl {
    public void findById(){
        fail("not found");
    }
}

class UserServiceImpl extends GenericServiceImpl {
    public void methodA() {
        findById();
    }
}

@Test
public void testSpy() {
    UserServiceImpl userService = Mockito.spy(new UserServiceImpl());

    Mockito.doNothing().when(userService).findById();

    userService.methodA();
}
```