# JUnit Superclass mocked method still called

Tags: java, unit-testing, inheritance, junit

I'm trying to write my Unit Tests for a class which extends another. I'm calling a superclass method in another child class method :

The child class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(PUBLIC_BASE_URL)
public class RequeteSASRestController extends BaseController {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

private final RequeteSASService requeteSASService;

@Inject
public RequeteSASRestController(
        final RequeteSASService pRequeteSASJdbcService) {
    requeteSASService = pRequeteSASJdbcService;
}

@ApiOperation(value = "Lecture d'une liste des requetes SAS", responseContainer = "List")
@RequestMapping(value = "/statistiques/requeteSAS", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<SimpleServiceResponse<List<RequeteSAS>>> readListeRequeteSas() {
    LOGGER.debug(" readListeRequeteSas()  ->");
    String remoteUser=super.getCurrentUserLogin();
    return this.ok(requeteSASService.readListeRequeteSas(remoteUser));
}
```

The superclass

```
public class BaseController {

public String getCurrentUserLogin() {
    //Some things
}
```

And finally here's my test class :

```
public class RequeteSASRestTest extends Mockito{

private RequeteSAS requeteSASJdbc1;
private RequeteSAS requeteSASJdbc2;
private RequeteSAS requeteSASJdbc1suppr;

/** Service RequeteSAS */
private RequeteSASService mockRequeteService;

/** Rest Controller. */
private RequeteSASRestController restController;


// Before : mock des services
@Before
public void beforeTests() throws FileNotFoundException {
    clearSecurityContext();
    mockRequeteService = mock(RequeteSASService.class);
    restController = Mockito.spy(new RequeteSASRestController(mockRequeteService));
    requeteSASJdbc1 = RequeteSASTestUtil.createRequeteSAS(//instance constructor);

    requeteSASJdbc2 = RequeteSASTestUtil.createRequeteSAS(//instance constructor);
}
@Test
public void testGetRequetes() {
    String mockRemoteUser = "STATT-00016-0102035";
    List<RequeteSAS> listReqTest = new ArrayList<RequeteSAS>();
    listReqTest.add(requeteSASJdbc1);
    listReqTest.add(requeteSASJdbc2);
    Mockito.doReturn(listReqTest).when(mockRequeteService).readListeRequeteSas(mockRemoteUser);
    Mockito.doReturn(mockRemoteUser).when((BaseController)restController).getCurrentUserLogin();
    ResponseEntity<SimpleServiceResponse<List<RequeteSAS>>> repReq = restController.readListeRequeteSas();
    List<RequeteSAS> listReq = repReq.getBody().getValue();
    //Assert List
}
```

As I said, with this, the method "getCurrentUserLogin()" from BaseController is still called, it does not return the mockRemoteUser. I've read many thread on this exact subject i.e. mocking a superclass method, I followed the answer, but still my test fails because "getCurrentUserLogin()" returns null instead of the mocked user.

Does somebody see where the problem is? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you *extend* Mockito? If you want to use stuff without `Mockito . ` in front of it - simply import it statically. Using inheritance like you do it here ... is basically bad practice.

Comment: The answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass says it's not possible and to use composition over inheritance.