# How to test Inheritance, or my design is wrong?

Tags: java, unit-testing, inheritance, composition, factory-pattern

I am trying to refactor a code. For sake of understanding, the code is about doing `actionX`.

The old code only works for order which are in `PENDING` state. In this state, the `actionX` is done for `activeOrders`. Before doing `actionX` there are small steps like `fetchA`, `fetchB` and `fetchC`. This piece of code has a `metaData` object which has some extra information. All `fetch*` are performed using this `metaData`. `fetchA` and `fetchB` are dependent on each other however, `fetchC` is independent from other `fetches`.

Now, a new status has been introduced. It's called `SHIPPED`. In this case, `actionY` needs to be done. The only common part in in this status and in `PENDING` is doing `fetchC`.

To me this appeared to be a perfect candidate to apply `FactoryPattern`. So i created a base class (not the interface since `fetchC` is common) and from that i created two children. `ActionYHandler` and `ActionXHandler`. The factory would take in `orderType` and would return either `ActionYHandler` or `ActionXHandler`.

Each handler will have a method `handle (MetaData metaData)` to process their specific action. However, `fetchC` was implemented as part of the super class i.e., `ActionHandler`. So that there is less code redundancy. Each handler needs to utilize data returned by `fetchC`. So by implementing `fetchC` at parent level, they can just call their parent method.

Everything works out perfect until i started writing unit test cases using `Mockito`. The problem occured when i tried to mock `fetchC` using `actionHandlerXMock` object. The error that i got is listed at the bottom of this post.

The error kind of make sense, so i started googling and [stumbled upon this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass) which has started to make me think that my design is wrong. So here are questions.

1. Should `fetchC` be part of parent class. If yes, then how can it be tested
2. The other option that i could think of is implement `fetchC` method at `factory` level and pass the data retrieved from `factory.fetchC` to `handle (MetaData metaData, FetchCResult fetchCResult)`. From testing perspective, this data can be then mocked easily. But it kind of defy the purpose of factory. Now factory has to be aware of some business logic here.

**ERROR Trace**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
at <my_class_name>
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(Unknown Source)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Answer (score 1):

UnitTests verify **behavior**.

*inheritance* is an **implementation detail** whch you do not test (explicitly).