# Mockito to throw exception when calling super method

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, junit4, jmockit

I have the following piece of code which calls the super method. I have to write mockito in such a way that, when the super method gets called, it has to throw an exception.

**Code:**

```
    Class A extends PoiItemReader{

    @Override
    public void read(){
        try{
            super.read();
        }
        catch(FileNotFound e){
            //logger
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried spy to this class, But the flow enters the super method and returns to the end of the method.

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass

Comment: I have tried that already and it worked!!!.. But when i try to throw an exception instead of doNothing(), then the test case is not throwing any exception