# Mock super class method mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Im trying to mock a respose from the super class and try to test a method in the child class.
My class structure is

```
class Base
{
   String run();
}

class Child extends Base
{
  public String run(){
     String test = super.run();
     // Some code
  }
}
```

I tried to mock it like this

```
Child child = Mockito.spy(new Child ());
Mockito.doreturn("abc").when((Base)child).run();
String result = child.run();
```

This will mock the run method in child class as well. Is there any other way to do it ?

Similar type of a question discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass). But the accepted answer suggest to refactor the code which is not a possibility in my case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mockito How to mock only the call of a method of the superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass)

Comment: The above thread does not have the answer to the specific problem im referring to