# How to mock super function of abstract class which is called by a function of sub class

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

I am writing a unit test for a class which extends from abstract class, one function of sub class will call super void function and function.

```
//two classes in different package

public abstract class AbstractBo {
    private Map myMap = new HashMap();
    protected void load(String jsonString) {
        //convert the jsonString parameter to map, and set to myMap
    }
    public String getItem(String key) {
        return myMap(Key);
    }
}

public class SubBo extends AbstractBo {
    public String submit(String initString) {
        //init a map by super function
       this.load(initString);
       return this.getItem("myName");
    }
}
```

I just want to test submit function, mock the load and getItem function.  I am new to powermock.

Comment: You should seriously consider to change your code, instead of looking towards PowerMock to work around your hard-to-test design. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass for example.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, you should try to avoid Powermock as far as you can, since it's usually associated with bad code design.
You actually don't need to use it in this case, since Mockito covers this case with [spies](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16), which is itself a bad code smell as stated in the documentation.

My suggestion is to change the code using composition over inheritance.

Still, if you are stuck with the code as it is, just add Junit and Mockito to your dependencies and write a test like:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SubBoTest {

  @Test
  public void shouldBehaveAsExpected() {
    final String expected = "expected String";
    final String testString = "test string";

    final SubBo bo = spy(SubBo.class);
    doNothing().when(bo).load(eq(testString));
    when(bo.getItem("myName")).thenReturn(expected);

    final String actual = bo.submit(testString);

    assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }
}
```

Again, please be reminded that this is not the proper way to go, and refactoring is advisable.