# Mockito stubbed method not being called

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm new to Mockito and have been having trouble with stubbing. I wanted to test a method but stub one line of that method which is a call to another class's method. Based on the code below, I was expecting Optional.empty() but got Optional.of("str should not be null"). What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ClassA {
    public String str;

    public Optional<String> method1() {
        if (str == null) { 
            return Optional.of("str should not be null"); 
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
        
public class ClassB {
    public String thing;
    public Optional<String> method2() {
        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        Optional<String> str2 = classA.method1();
        if (str2.isPresent()) return str2;
        if (thing == null) return Optional.of("thing should not be null");
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

public class ClassBTest {
    @Test
    public void method1_test() {
        ClassB classBSpy = spy(new ClassB());
        ClassA classASpy = spy(new ClassA());
        doReturn(Optional.empty()).when(classASpy).method1();

        assertEquals(Optional.empty(), classBSpy.method2());
    }
}
```

Comment: can't reproduce; Test succeded.

Comment: @Turo I have changed the code to use composition instead of inheritance. The test still fails. Can you try it again and see if it works for you?

Comment: Now it must fail since classBSpy has its own ClassA Object, not the Spy and your stubbing of classASpy is useless

Comment: What is the correct way then to stub the method call classA.method1()? I replaced the classBSpy in the test with ClassB classB = new ClassB() and assertEquals(Optional.empty, classB.method2()) but that also failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a stub of ClassA effective in ClaasB, you need a way to insert the Spy/Mock of CLassA into CLassB, i.e. through the constructor:

```
public class ClassB {
    public String thing;

    private ClassA classA = new ClassA();

    public ClassB() {
        super();
    }


    public ClassB(ClassA classA) {
        super();
        this.classA = classA;
    }

    public Optional<String> method2() {
        Optional<String> str2 = classA.method1();
        if (str2.isPresent()) return str2;
        if (thing == null) return Optional.of("thing should not be null");
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
 

public class ClassBTest {
    @Test
    public void method1_test() {
        ClassA classASpy = spy(new ClassA());
        ClassB classB = new ClassB(classASpy);
        doReturn(Optional.empty()).when(classASpy).method1();

        assertEquals(Optional.empty(), classB.method2());
    }
}
```

But the test still fails since `Optional.empty().isPresent()` is `false` and `thing` is awlays `null`.

Comment: But why? I don't understand - is there any way to stub the method call classA.method1() without having to insert a ClassA instance variable into ClassB? Doesn't this defeat the purpose of mocking/stubbing out dependencies?

Comment: No, But if you use injection it's easily done for you by Annotiations.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the test you have provided here executes successfully, I'm not a Mockito expert, but I think this is mainly because it will simply stub the method based on the method signature, return Optional.empty() and not care about the cast.

If I understood correctly, in case you want to stub the super call of that method, I don't think that Mockito supports this. There was thread about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467801/mockito-how-to-mock-only-the-call-of-a-method-of-the-superclass). You could however turn to PowerMockito for that, I believe it might have such capabilities.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I refactored the code to use composition instead of inheritance but it is failing now. I edited the question to reflect the correct code. Can you try running the test again?